# How do i get the `ResponseDescription` value in Microsoft Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

So the column i'm querying has an XML data that looks like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://google.com/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:response xmlns:ns2="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <trackingId>1375321435</trackingId>
            <responseCode>202</responseCode>
            <responseDescription>Request completed successfully</responseDescription>
            <detail>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> &lt;LoanProcessResponse>     &lt;ResponseCode>E4284&lt;/ResponseCode>     &lt;ResponseDescription>The minimum value date allowed for this account must be greater than [08-12-2022].: acctDisburseTranLA.valueDate&lt;/ResponseDescription>     &lt;status>FAILURE&lt;/status> &lt;/LoanProcessResponse></detail>
        </ns2:response>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

```
and my query looks like the below
```

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://google.com/' AS soap, 'http://stackoverflow.com/' AS ns2)
SELECT
    timeSent, 
    accountNo,
    isSuccessful,
    try_convert(xml, responsePayload).query('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:response/detail/LoanProcessResponse/ResponseDescription') AS response
from my_table
where accountNo = '000000008'
ORDER BY timesent desc;
```

```
Can you help me get the value of the  <ResponseDescription> without the tag?
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your database and its version.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is better to use XML data type for the **responsePayload** column.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, responsePayload NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (responsePayload) VALUES
(N'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://google.com/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:response xmlns:ns2="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <trackingId>1375321435</trackingId>
            <responseCode>202</responseCode>
            <responseDescription>Request completed successfully</responseDescription>
            <detail>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> &lt;LoanProcessResponse>     &lt;ResponseCode>E4284&lt;/ResponseCode>     &lt;ResponseDescription>The minimum value date allowed for this account must be greater than [08-12-2022].: acctDisburseTranLA.valueDate&lt;/ResponseDescription>     &lt;status>FAILURE&lt;/status> &lt;/LoanProcessResponse></detail>
        </ns2:response>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://google.com/' AS soap, 'http://stackoverflow.com/' AS ns2)
SELECT ID 
    , responseDescription = TRY_CAST(responsePayload AS XML)
        .value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:response/responseDescription/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)')
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

| ID | responseDescription |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Request completed successfully |